# Show that P[a,b] is a strict subset of C[a,b]; in other words, there are necessarily nonpolynomial elements in C[a, b].

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, continuity

Let $P([a, b])$ denote the space of all polynomials on $[a, b]$. Clearly $P([a, b]) \subseteq C([a, b])$.  Show that $P([a,b])$ is a strict subset of $C([a,b])$; in other words, there are necessarily nonpolynomial elements in $C([a, b])$.

Comment: By $C([a,b])$, do you mean continuous functions, smooth functions, or something else? In any case, just find such a function which is not a polynomial, like $e^x$!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A different approach. All polinomials are differentiable (in fact $C^\infty$.) Any continuous function which is not derivabkle at some point is not a polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

**Claim.** We use the property if $f(x)$ has infinite number of roots and it is non constant then $f$ is not a polynomial. (why?)

We will prove this on $[0,1]$, the solution here can easily be transferred to any interval $[a,b]$.

Take $f(x) =x \sin(1/x)$, then $f$ is continuous (why?) and has infinite number of roots(why?). Therefore from claim $f$ is not a polynomial.

Comment: Minor point: "and $f(0) = 0$", for your example.